# What's wrong with my self-written Calculator.java?

Tags: java, algorithm, syntax, calculator

I have written a little calculator in java but it doesn't do what it is supposed to.. :p

So if I enter "a" in the console, it will do the addition as wished. But if I want do another operation, as example multiplication, typing "m" does nothing.

Other operations only seem to work if you go this order in the console (a,s,m,d), probably because that's the order in the code below.

But how can I fix this problem? I want if I type "m" that multiplication is done, or if I type "d" that division is done. What is my mistake here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double x = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("a: addition");
        System.out.println("s: subtraction");
        System.out.println("m: multiplication");
        System.out.println("d: division");

        if(input.nextLine().equals("a")){
            double add;
            add=x+y;
            System.out.println(add);
        }
        else if(input.next().equals("s")){
            double sub;
            sub=x-y;
            System.out.println(sub);
        }
        else if(input.next().equals("m")){
            double mul;
            mul=x*y;
            System.out.println(mul);
        }
        else if(input.next().equals("d")){
            double div;
            div=x/y;
            System.out.println(div);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time you are calling `next` or `nextLine` you are asking for new data. You shouldn't be doing it in each `if` but once before and reuse results in `if`s.

Comment: Every time you call `input.nextFoo` you consume the next token. Store it before you compare. Or use a `switch`.

Comment: Every time you call `nextLine()` or `next()` in your if conditions, they are actually consuming the input. Save the input in a variable and check the value of the variable instead. Something like `String choice = input.nextLine(); if(choice.equals("a"))...`.

Comment: Thanks! How would you "store" it? Edit: I think I understood. Let me try to do it.

Comment: Awesome, now it's working :)

Comment: Assign it to a variable......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute several operations, one after the other one, you should retrieve both the operator and the number from the application and use a loop to allow it instead of providing the numbers as args in your program.

Otherwise you should run your program as much as you need to perform some calculs and it seems undesirable for a Calculator usecase.

Besides, you should avoid mixing `input.nextLine()` and `input.next()`, you risk to have some unpredictable results.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator{

    public static void main(String[] args){         
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       while (true){
         System.out.println("a: addition");
         System.out.println("s: subtraction");
         System.out.println("m: multiplication");
         System.out.println("d: division");
         System.out.println("q: quit");

         String operator = input.next();
         if (operator.equals("q"){
           return;
         }

         double x = input.nextDouble();
         double y = input.nextDouble();

        if(operator.equals("a")){
            double add;
            add=x+y;
            System.out.println(add);
        }
        else if(operator.equals("s")){
            double sub;
            sub=x-y;
            System.out.println(sub);
        }
        else if(operator.equals("m")){
            double mul;
            mul=x*y;
            System.out.println(mul);
        }
        else if(operator.equals("d")){
            double div;
            div=x/y;
            System.out.println(div);
        }

         else{
           System.out.println("enter one of the proposed options");
         }

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tyvm I just asked myself how I could avoid using arguments and type them in the console instead. Also I just realized I have mixed both line and nextLine ^.^ Is there any difference btw? Maybe it's like print and println?

Comment: If you use `next()` and you enter for example the `hello` value and then you use `nextLine()`, then  the scanner  will read the remain of the current line, that is an empty String : ""

Comment: I have one more question regarding your while loop. It says "as long as it's true, repeat". But as long as what is true exactly? Or this is some kind of trick I need to keep in mind?

Comment: I had written the exit condition `if (operator.equals(""){
           return;
         }` just after the user is requested to select its operator. A empty String exited the loop. I modified the condition to have an explicit value to quit : `q`.
I have just also added a message if the requested operation doesn't exist.

Comment: I have a similar question on algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556775/populate-string-value-in-a-map-only-if-matches-the-threshold-bytes). Trying to make fixed size string before putting it into map. I am not sure I got it right so wanted to check with you.

Answer (score 1):

Read your input, then do your logic.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double x = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("a: addition");
        System.out.println("s: subtraction");
        System.out.println("m: multiplication");
        System.out.println("d: division");

        String operator = input.nextLine();

        if(operator.equals("a")){
            double add;
            add=x+y;
            System.out.println(add);
        }
        else if(operator.equals("s")){
            double sub;
            sub=x-y;
            System.out.println(sub);
        }
        else if(operator.equals("m")){
            double mul;
            mul=x*y;
            System.out.println(mul);
        }
        else if(operator.equals("d")){
            double div;
            div=x/y;
            System.out.println(div);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem you were facing is that each `if` statement was reading from the input and exhausting the input from `System.in`. So, it read a line and compared it to "a". If it was "a", it did addition like you said. **Otherwise**, it went on, **trys to read the next character from System.in**, and compares that to "s". Etc for "m" and "d".

Rather than read so much input, what you really want is to read the input once (`String operator = input.nextLine()`)  and compare that string to your operator strings.

Comment: Thank you it works now! If you have time to answer I have an additional question; Why doesn't the code work if you take String operator = input.nextLine() and write it before you write the System.out.println("..")'s?

Comment: Oh, the code will work if you do that, but it wouldn't make sense to receive instructions *after* you've provided your input.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call next() or nextLine(), it would expect input at runtime.
So, first, call next() or nextLine() only once per input.

To keep performing operations, you have to run through a loop. You can make it more interactive as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double x = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

do{

        System.out.println("a: addition");
        System.out.println("s: subtraction");
        System.out.println("m: multiplication");
        System.out.println("d: division");

    String input = new Scanner(System.in).next();

    if(input.equals("a")){
            double add;
            add=x+y;
            System.out.println(add);
        }
        else if(input.equals("s")){
            double sub;
            sub=x-y;
            System.out.println(sub);
        }
        else if(input.equals("m")){
            double mul;
            mul=x*y;
            System.out.println(mul);
        }
        else if(input.equals("d")){
            double div;
            div=x/y;
            System.out.println(div);
        }

    System.out.print("Want to calculate more (Y/N) : ");
    String choice = new Scanner(System.in).next();
    if(choice.equals("N") || choice.equals("n"))
        break;
    else if(choice.equals("Y") || choice.equals("y"))
        continue;
    else{
            System.out.println("Bad choice");
            break;
    }

}while(true);
    }
}
```