# Populate string value in a map only if matches the threshold bytes

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, utf-8, stringbuilder

I have a `tasks` list object which I am iterating and appending each task object into `StringBuilder` followed by new line as shown below. Now I will keep appending task object in same string builder until it reaches a size limit of 60000 bytes. Once it reaches the limit, I will populate this string as a value in the map and key will be file name with incremental index. And then I will reset string builder and other thing and repeat this process again.

So if I have a big `tasks` object, then I will split into multiple string object whose size should always be less than 60000 bytes.

I got below code but I always see value in the map has size greater than 60000 bytes. Anything wrong I am doing? Also I am populating into `HashMap` at two different places - one if limit is reached and other is if limit is not reached.

```
  public void populate(final List<Task> tasks) {
    Map<String, String> holder = new HashMap<>();
    int size = 0;
    int index = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Task task : tasks) {
      sb.append(task).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
      size = sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
      if (size > 60000) {
        String fileName = "tasks_info_" + index + ".txt";
        holder.put(fileName, sb.toString());
        index++;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        size = 0;
      }
    }
    // for cases where we don't reach the limit
    if(sb.toString().length > 0) {
        String fileName = "tasks_info_" + index + ".txt";
        holder.put(fileName, sb.toString());        
    }
    System.out.println(holder);
  }
```

**Note:** If each Task object is more than `60000 bytes`, then I will drop that object right away and move to next entry. But in real, its not gonna happen.

**Update:**

```
public void populate(final List<Task> tasks, final long timestamp) {
    Map<String, String> holder = new HashMap<>();
    int size = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int nl = System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // new change
    sb.append(timestamp).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    for (Task task : tasks) {
        int ts = String.valueOf(task).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
        if (size + ts + nl > 60000) {
            String fileName = "tasks_info_" + index + ".txt";
            holder.put(fileName, sb.toString());
            index++;
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            // new change
            sb.append(timestamp).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));          
            size = 0;
        }
        sb.append(task).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        size += ts + nl;
    }
    // for cases where we don't reach the limit
    if (size > 0) { // size can only be 0 if you have 0 tasks
        String fileName = "tasks_info_" + index + ".txt";
        holder.put(fileName, sb.toString());        
    }
    System.out.println(holder);
}
```

Comment: @MickMnemonic updated the question with details you asked.

Comment: You need not to increment variable size, just assign it to sb size in bytes. And do it before "if (size > 60000)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it is not working was already mentioned by other answers (you add after it already exceeded the limit). But I think none of the implementations is correct so far, not only because the size of the newline was ommitted.

```
public Map<String, String> populate(final List<Task> tasks) {
    Map<String, String> holder = new HashMap<>();
    if (tasks.size() == 0)
        return holder;
    int index = 0;
    int nl = System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(System.currentTimeMillis()).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    int size = sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
    for (Task task : tasks) {
        int ts = String.valueOf(task).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
        if (size + ts + nl > 60000) {
            String fileName = "tasks_info_" + index + ".txt";
            holder.put(fileName, sb.toString());
            index++;
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(System.currentTimeMillis()).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            size = sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
        }
        sb.append(task).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        size += ts + nl;
    }
    String fileName = "tasks_info_" + index + ".txt";
    holder.put(fileName, sb.toString());        
    return holder;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I need to return map from my method. I was just printing so that I can test out. In real, I am returning a map.

Comment: quick question where do you check size for `stringbuilder` in your example? do we need that or we dont need it anymore now?

Comment: Yes it isn't needed any more. We add the task and newline to size each time. The stringbuilder size should be the same as the cumulated size for the tasks (because we use int and no compression is happening).

Comment: got it.. I have one more question. I updated my question with your code and I added one changes to it (look for "new change" comment). Let's say if I generating 10 files so my map will have 10 entries in it. Now I want to add timestamp in the first line of each file, followed by new line and then followed by data. So will your solution still work or now I need to make some changes so that it still follows the size limit?

Comment: You need to add the size for the timestamp and newline to the check, otherwise no changes. If the format is always the same (e.g. yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss), then it is just a constant. If not (e.g. because leading 0s are ommitted) then it can become a little tricky unless you just take the longest possible timestamp string as constant. (size + ts + nl + timestampsize + nl > 60000) or maybe more readable (size + ts + nl > 60000 - timestampsize - nl)

Comment: my timestamp will always be in long. can you provide an example basis on this as well how it will look now which includes timestamp and another new line check?

Comment: @user1950349 edited answer to work with header (timestamp + newline)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164654/discussion-between-user1950349-and-maraca).

Comment: @user1950349 updated the answer, now returning the map and other small optimization (check if tasks is 0 at the top, then you don't need the if at the bottom, was needed to make the logic correct if you have 0 tasks or you would get a map with a file with only a timestamp in it).

Comment: we still need the last if check right? what happens if for loop is finished then won't it create one extra file again if we don't do last if check?

Comment: @user1950349 no that is not possible, you create a file if the task to add would exceed the limit, so the task which triggers the file creation is always added afterwards and not to the file which was just created.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code to be sure of the solution. You need to try to check the next size before actually adding the new task's value to SB. I modified the code to reflect this solution. Could you try this out and tell us if it worked for you or not ?

```
public  void populate(final List<Task> tasks) {
        Map<String, String> holder = new HashMap<>();
        int size = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int lengthTask = 0;
        int lengthSb = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            lengthTask = task.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
            lengthSb = sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
            if (size + lengthTask + lengthSb > 60000) {
                System.out.println("last added size "+size);
                String fileName = "tasks_info_" + index + ".txt";
                holder.put(fileName, sb.toString());
                index++;
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                size = 0;
            }
            sb.append(task).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            size += sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
            System.out.println("size "+size);

        }
        // for cases where we don't reach the limit
        String fileName = "tasks_info_" + index + ".txt";
        holder.put(fileName, sb.toString());
        System.out.println(holder);
    }
```

Comment: While I do agree with this answer, you already have the size, so you could just move the `size += sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;` line before the `if` and do the check on that. No need for the auxiliary `lengthSb`

Comment: That was my initial solution however when I checked last size added to map, resulting size was shown over the target value (60 000). That's when I came to the conclusion that potential size which will result after the addition, should be checked before actually adding the current item. To clarify , I had implemented that solution and just now re-implemented and executed again to be sure. Result is sb size exceeding the  target value.

Comment: Admittedly the solution I posted above is tailored to the example code given by the question.  If the goal is to have each value in the resulting hashmap to be just under 60000, instead of cumulative adding (+=) the size of sb, it is better to just check  sum of task and sb lengths ( if(task.length+sb.length > 60000) )  then decide to add sb to hashmap,  then add the task to sb.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the code correctly, I guess it should be

```
 size = sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
```

And currently it inserts to map after the string has size greater than 60000 bytes, so the values in the map have more than 60000 bytes

```
if (size > 60000) {
    ...
    holder.put(fileName, sb.toString());
    ...
}
```

Comment: @user1950349 I guess you want operator = instead of +=?

Comment: @user1950349 sorry, I don't get it. Do you want each value of map has less than 60000 bytes or the total size of of values of map has less than 60000 bytes?

Comment: I am appending task object in a stringbuilder followed by new line so I want to store stringbuilder as a string in a map only if that stringbuilder is less than 60000 bytes. If it is more than, I will put as another entry.

Comment: @user1950349 I guess after appending things to string builder, you should update size variable first? instead of the 'if (size > 60000) check'

Comment: @user1950349  "store stringbuilder as a string in a map only if that stringbuilder is less than 60000 bytes."
This confuses me because you also store the string if its size > 60000 in the if clause